# Fractional ideals of integral extensions of Dedekind domains are generated by two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain. In Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*, it is an exercise to show that any fractional ideal of $R$ is of the form $(a,b)$. If $A$ is an integral extension of $R$, can we generalize the previous statement to $A$?

Comment: Note that having unique prime ideal factorization is (basically) equivalent to being a Dedekind domain. If $L=\text{Frac}(A)$ is a *finite* extension of $K=\text{Frac}(R)$, then this is true, see https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2016fa/LectureNotes5.pdf

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Do you mean that A is also a Dedekind domain? Do we need A to be an integral closure of R?

Answer (score 2):

Taking $R = \mathbf Z$, orders in number fields are integral extensions of $R$. For every number field of degree at least $3$, there is an order containing an ideal that does not have a $2$-element generating set.

**Example**.  For a number field $K$ of degree $n \geq 3$ and an integer $c \geq 2$, set $A = \mathbf Z + c\mathcal O_K$, which is an integral extension of $\mathbf Z$. Let $\mathfrak a = c\mathcal O_K$. It is an ideal in both $A$ and $\mathcal O_K$.  Although $\mathfrak a$ is a principal ideal in $\mathcal O_K$, it can't be generated by less than $n$ elements as an ideal in $A$!  (There is an $n$-element generating set as an ideal since $\mathfrak a \cong \mathbf Z^n$ as an abelian group and thus $\mathfrak a$ already has an $n$-element generating set as a $\mathbf Z$-module.) For a proof that $\mathfrak a$ has no generating set as an ideal in $A$ with less than $n$ elements, read Remark $2.3$ [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/conductor.pdf).

The restriction above to degree at least $3$ is reasonable: in an order in a number field of degree $2$, each nonzero ideal has $2$ generators as a $\mathbf Z$-module, and $\mathbf Z$-module generators also work as generators of the ideal.